# Retrieve tables with similar columns mysql

Tags: mysql

My tables look like this:

reg table

```
id  | user_id
--------------
7   | 8
10  | 11
```

location table

```
id | reg_id | location_number
-----------------------------
4  | 7      | 111111
5  | 10     | 222222
6  | 10     | 333333
```

machines table

```
id | location_id | type
-----------------------
1  | 4           | local
2  | 5           | local
3  | 6           | international
```

---

The result that i want is to retrieve reg_id's that are the same along with other related data as shown below:

```
reg_id  | location_number | user_id | location_id
-------------------------------------------------
10      | 222222          | 11      | 5
10      | 333333          | 11      | 6
```

---

The query that I have is:

```
select * from reg
join location on reg.id = location.reg_id
join machines on location.id = machines.location_id
where reg.id = 10
```

But this query only returns one row.

Need assistance in achieving the above result. Thanks

Comment: With the sample data in the question t3wo rows will be returned, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/421ce/1 for an example. Check your data/query again.

Comment: I have been trying that same approach in phpmyadmin and in POSTMAN(chrome plugin) but it only retrieves one one. Is there another approach that could be used? -@jpw

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
    select location.reg_id, location. location_number, reg.user_id, machines.location_id 
    from reg
    join location on reg.id = location.reg_id
    join machines on location.id = machines.location_id
    where reg.id = 10
```